# Using globs in the sudoers file

Tags: sudo, wildcards

The following man page states that, "sudo allows shell-style wildcards (aka meta or glob characters) to be used in host names, path names and command line arguments in the sudoers file."

https://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers

I've added the following to my sudoers file which allows the support user to start the Postfix service.

```
support     ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl start postfix
```

Instead of adding multiple commands for each start, stop, restart action, I thought that I'd try to use globbing to match each case. Using https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/glob I came up with the glob string below.

[image]

Unfortunately this doesn't work. No syntax errors are generated, so that's good.

Does anyone have any ideas that I could try?

Comment: You are not asking this, but the reason what you're trying does not work is that what you're trying is an extended globbing pattern, whereas the type of patterns that are valid in the `sudoers` file are standard globbing patterns (not `?(...)`, `*(...)`, `+(...)`, `@(...)`).

Comment: Thanks for the info. You're welcome to post that as the answer and I'll accept it. Using your answers I've found https://www.sudo.ws/pipermail/sudo-users/2022-March/006477.html which mentions that "beginning with version 1.9.10, sudo supports POSIX regular expressions". Perhaps I'll upgrade the package and try that.

Comment: You may post a self-answer if you wish. I did not write an answer because your question was not about _why_ but about _how_, which my comment does not answer.

Answer (score 0):

The sudoers file only supports standard globbing, not extended globbing. See the following thread for more detail.

https://www.sudo.ws/pipermail/sudo-users/2022-March/006475.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).